# How to add dynamic/multi button in UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

How to add dynamic/multi button in UINavigatation Bar?

Like below image:

[image: logmein tool bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UIToolBar which then hold hold multiple UIBarButtonItem objects.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    // create a toolbar to have two buttons in the right

        UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];

        // create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
        NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

        // create a standard "add" button
        UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add)];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];
        [bi release];


        // create a standard "refresh" button
        bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];
        [bi release];

        // stick the buttons in the toolbar
        [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

        [buttons release];

        // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
        [tools release];

}

-(void)add{
    NSLog(@"Code to add the row in tableview");
}

-(void)refresh {
    NSLog(@"code to refresh the tableView");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't shore about iOS5, but in iOS4 you can do this only sublussing (or even making your own) nav. bar in reason to make it custom.